# Performed an ajax request. How do I format the returning data?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

The below ajax request works. However, it is not ideal. The HttpContext is proving to be difficult to work with. Context.Response.Clear() does absolutely nothing.

How is write what I want to the output without extra info?

Additionally, I would like this ajax request to access the RetrieveAddress class directly, but uncommenting the URL parameter gives me a HTTP 500 error. So right now, the ajax request just accesses the codebehind (IsPostBack is false...)

What is the proper syntax to have ajax access just one method?

```
    function showLocation(position) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //url: "ThisLocation.aspx/RetrieveAddress",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude
            },
            //datatype: "JSON",
            success: function (msg) {
                address1 = document.getElementById('address');

                //my illegitimate hack to retrieve only what I inserted
                address1.value = msg.substr(0, msg.indexOf('\n'));
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the codebehind. As of right now, what works is in the Page_Load method. I am not able to get the RetrieveAddress method to work.

```
public partial class ThisLocation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Common.CheckAnyLogin();

        //if we're coming from ajax request
        if (Context.Request["latitude"] != null && Context.Request["longitude"] != null)
        {
            double lat;
            double long;
            lat = Double.Parse(Context.Request["latitude"].ToString());
            long = Double.Parse(Context.Request["longitude"].ToString());

            //can i access this session from html after initial load?
            Session["MyLocAddress"] = GetAddress.GetAddressAll(lat, long);
            // Why doesn't this actually clear anything?
            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.Write(Session["MyLocAddress"].ToString());
        }
    }

    public static string RetrieveAddress(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        return GetAddress.GetAddressAll(latitude, longitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your page no longer exists on the server.  You should use a separate ASHX handler, and send JSON.

Comment: that can't be true if i am able to access the codebehind now. but once i am in the codebehind, how do i format the success results? right now I get the entire html in my return, when I just want the one line

Comment: You're accessing a completely new page instance, as if you opened another tab.  That's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use POST to an ASPX page, you need to include the method as a request parameter, not part of the URL. In your Ajax request:

```
data: {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            method: "RetrieveAddress"
        }
```

and then in codebehind:

```
if (Context.Request["method"] == "RetrieveAddress")
{
    Callyourmethod();
}
```

Cumbersome. This is the reason why I use web services instead of ASPX pages. With web services, you can access the methods directly from Ajax.

Comment: Hmm good idea. How do I then format the results? As it is, I get the entire html in my return, when I just want one line. Also, would GET be any better?

Comment: Response.Clear() should work.

You can use a JSON serializer like Newtonsoft to format the results, or just: response.write("{Text: \"MyAddress"\")") or something along those lines

Comment: Have you tried running Response.End() after the Clear()?

Comment: after throwing in a response.end() before my response.write("address"), now the msg returned is "".

Answer (score 0):

your missing Response.End(), technically, this should work...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Response.Clear();
      Response.Write("Hello");
      Response.End();
}
```

Also for accessing the method directly, you must use the [WebMethod]
 attribute for that...

```
[WebMethod]
public static string RetrieveAddress(double latitude, double longitude)
{
     return GetAddress.GetAddressAll(latitude, longitude);
}
```